# Blender Python Write text to plane

Tags: python, blender, blender-2.67, blender-2.76

Is it possible to write text in a Blender mesh plane from python? I need to change characters very quickly and the knife is not ideal.

Best

Answer (score 0):

Text object seems like the thing you are looking for `Add -> Text`. You can then change its content via python like this: `bpy.data.objects['Text'].data.body = 'some text'`.